# Sonar - Always use curly braces for if/else/for/while/do statements

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

So, I've analyzed my project with Sonar and I get this weird error: `Always use curly braces for if/else/for/while/do statements` I know normally what this mean (and I don't create blocks without curly braces) but in this case it's weird: The errors appears mostly at this types of code (when using && or ||) and I was wondering why:

```
if (isCreate && latitude && longitude) {
    ...some code here...
}
```

EDIT:

The entire code:

```
var map = Ext.getCmp('map_canvas').getMap();

    var latitude = Ext.getCmp('latitudeCmp').getValue();
    var longitude = Ext.getCmp('longitudeCmp').getValue();

    if (isCreate && latitude && longitude) {
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        map.setCenter(center);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: center, map: map,icon: staticPath+'/images/residence_gMap.png'});
        markersArray.push(marker);
    } else if (latitude && longitude) {
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        map.setCenter(center);
    } else if (!latitude && !longitude) {
        var siteEditAction = Seam.Component.getInstance('siteEditAction');
        siteEditAction.getGeolocalizationParameters(fillMapParamsCallback, exceptionHandler);
    }
```

Comment: Error or warning treated as an error?? You don't HAVE to use curly braces unless it's a block. And I assume your latitude and longitude variables are boolean??

Comment: When you drill down in the report what is the line it points to?

Comment: @basiljames It points at the first line, the one with the IF; It's shown as a major violation.

Comment: @PaulG I've updated my question with almost the entire code. isCreate is boolean but longitude and latitude are not, they are latitude and longitude values; If they were boolean I think I would had a naming problem :)

Comment: this isn't java code...?

Comment: @jtahlborn No, it's Javascript, don't know why I put Java in tags...changed it

Comment: Perchance it is expecting the curly brace to be on the next line?

Comment: @Shmiddty Don't think so because I have many if blocks in that file and only 2 or 3 of them are violating that violation :) But I'll run a test

Comment: On a side note, is Sonar complaining a deal-breaker? I mean, it's obviously wrong in this instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I answered in Sonar Mailing List ( http://markmail.org/message/dva7u5pxtggsiz7x ): you face with following two issues, which
will be fixed in next release -
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-2079 and
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-2200

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bug in the Sonar Javascript Plugin. Can you please report your case on the user@sonar.codhaus.org mailing list: our language team will have a look at it and maybe fill an issue on our JIRA.

Comment: Thank you, I'll fill a report about it... also there is one more thing about the violation: `Sections of code should not be "commented out"` ; I know that sometimes this is a bad practice but there are some comments that uses some "reserved" words (for example if I have a comment like : `START office messages` - in this case sonar evaluates it as a violation)

Comment: Or there will be times when you must use some code to do an explanation for the following method/function